# How to set different position for in-app keyboard in autolayout depending on phone's bezels?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder, iphone-x

I'm trying to make an application that includes a replica of the Japanese iOS keyboard.

I managed to recreate it in interface builder. I've embedded the keys in their own view, and autolayout for the keys works perfectly.

My issue is that I want the keyboard to match the system one exactly. The keyboard view should appear 4 pixels from the bottom on iPhone models with bezels and 80 pixels from the bottom for the X-series of iPhones to account for their lack of bezels.

I don't really want to hardcode the constraints based on the iPhone model. What is the best way to position the keyboard to account for both kinds of phones?

Is there a way to detect if an iPhone has bezels?

---

[image: Here's an image of my storyboard for the iPhone X.]

The only difference is:

iPhone X series:
`bottom = KeyboardView.bottom + 80`

Others: `bottom = KeyboardView.bottom + 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a UIInputViewController and its `inputView`. The "keyboard" (the input view) will automatically appear in the right place on all device types.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I thought you could only use it with keyboard extensions.

Comment: I just wanted to say that I found the section about it in your Programming iOS 12 book through google books. It was a huge help and I'm planning to pick up a copy once I get more experience with iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is trying to do the same thing, I finally figured it out.

I tried to have my view controller override `canBecomeFirstResponder` to return `true` and call `self.becomeFirstResponder()` to bring up the keyboard.
However, since the view controller is not a text field it won't position the keyboard as if it's a text keyboard. This may work if your custom input is a UIPickerView, but it doesn't work for a text keyboard. You have to call `becomeFirstResponder()` on a UITextField for the system to position your keyboard correctly.

Also, when you set the layout constraints, you can't use

`keyboardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)])`

or even

`keyboardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)])`

This pins your keyboard to the bottom, and doesn't leave enough room underneath it.

---

Here's my solution:

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)
    let keyboardView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil).first as! KeyboardView

    guard let inputView = self.inputView else { return }
    inputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    inputView.addSubview(keyboardView)

    keyboardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      keyboardView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputView.leftAnchor),
      keyboardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputView.topAnchor),
      keyboardView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputView.rightAnchor)])
  } 
}
```

and for my view controller, I just do:

```
  let keyboardViewController = KeyboardViewController()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.inputView = self.keyboardViewController.inputView
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
  }
```

---

If you have any suggestions, or know how to bring up a keyboard without calling `becomeFirstResponder()` on a text field, please let me know.

Hopefully this will help someone out.